# JS scripts break down after locally wordpress installation

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a strange problem when trying to install a wordpress locally - so all the downloaded js scripts, both those in the theme and those in the wp-admin, crashes.

I thought it might be an environmental problem, but I have locally installed other wordpresses on which the problem doesn't occur, and I tested it on various configurations: Windows + XAMPP (php 5.6/7.2), MacOS + MAMP (php 7.0) + vHost.
Here are screens of scripts (jquery from a theme are just an example, it happens with every script in the application) 
[chrome webdev tools screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95BRP.png), [sublime text screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNOYy.png), [front console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjlSq.png), [wp-admin console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72tnk.png)

Comment: Those screenshots are of little help. What is your console log saying is the issue?

Comment: I have edited the post and added more screens from console

Answer (score 0):

The problem is all those `<0x00>` characters in your js files. The quick and easy fix is to delete all of those characters (just use find and replace so it's quick).

For a proper solution you need to look at your server and where these characters came from. If you're running nginx try adding this to your config

```
 sendfile  off;
```

as suggested in [this serverfault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/269420/disable-caching-when-serving-static-files-with-nginx-for-development/645425#645425).